# Flutter widget that is listening to a riverpod provider is not updating

Tags: flutter, dart, state, provider, riverpod

Here is the provider:

```
final randomValueProivider =  StateNotifierProvider<RandomStateNotifier,
    double>(
        (ref) {return RandomStateNotifier(1);});

class RandomStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<double>{
  RandomStateNotifier(super. State);
}
```

I am listening to the provider like so :

```
double _currentServiceRequestProvider = ref.watch(randomValueProivider);
```

here is the widget below

```
Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Text("Random "
                                              "$_currentServiceRequestProvider")
                                        ],
                                      ),
```

there is a slider widget that changes the number as the user slides it

```
   FlutterSlider(
                                        values: [10],
                                        max: 10,
                                        min: 0,
                                        onDragging: (handlerIndex, lowerValue, upperValue) {


                                          ref.watch
                                            (currentServiceRequestProvider
                                              .notifier).updateBedrooms(lowerValue);

                                          ref.watch
                                            (currentServiceRequestProvider
                                              .notifier).updateBedrooms(lowerValue);


                                          _currentServiceRequestProvider = lowerValue;


                                          logger.d(ref.watch
                                            (currentServiceRequestProvider
                                              .notifier).state.Randomnumber);

                                        },
                                      ),
```

the slider above does work and it does update the random number, I can then see the updated number through the logger but the text widget does not update

I have declared a state notifier provider that holds a double value, there is a slider widget that allows the user to select a number they want, this widget then updates the provider, which I expect the Text widget to show the new number but it does not show the new number

Comment: Your text needs to be in a stateful widget and in the slider onDragging parameter you need to add SetState(): to update the builder

Comment: Where did you put `double _currentServiceRequestProvider = ref.watch(randomValueProivider);` You need to watch it in `build` method.

Comment: I am watching it from a build method, I have been using other providers and they are working fine but this one isnt

Comment: Please stop using StateNotifier: The literature is rushing to catch up with Remi's prolific development.  In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Answer (score 0):

Well.. You didn't provide us with how you implement this "randomNumber". Is that a property instead of a function? How does it work?
Also you shouldn't use ref.watch inside event handler, use ref.read instead.
Read the currentServiceRequestProvider's notifier, and call the randomNumber() function. The function should be something like this:

```
void randomNumber() {
    var random = new Random();
    state = random.nextInt(100);
}
```